# How to make modal responsive?

Tags: html, .net, bootstrap-4

I have implemented this bootstrap modal box. It works perfect, and it is quite easy to use.However, it is not responsive. how can we make its responsive? please help.

```
@model LEOCoins.Entities.Models.AccountStatementTableModel

<div class="row pb-5">
<div class="col-lg-6 font-weight-bold">
    @Model.Date
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 font-weight-bold text-right">
    @Model.Text
</div>
</div>
<table class="display nowrap dataTable dtr-inline collapsed">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Details</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Balance</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var line in Model.Lines)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@line.Id</td>
            <td>@(line.Date.HasValue ? line.Date.Value.AddHours(5).ToString() : "-")</td>
            <td>@line.Details</td>
            <td>@line.Quantity</td>
            <td>@line.Balance</td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

Comment: Bootstrap has classes for different resolutions. You have used "col-lg-6", but you can also use "col-sm-6" or "col-6". + You can write also different css for different resolutions using @media rules. You can use different resolution classes same time, like class="col-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-lg-4"

Comment: Can you re-write code as responsive @Andris

Comment: Depends what you need. It could be just enough to add classes. Take a look here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: I just want responsive as it could be display on mobile phones. @Andris